# Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, requirejs

I'm getting this error message after an update that the developer of the plugin performed and it seems to be completely broken now. Is there a way I can fix this error myself?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "checked: function (){return canShip }"
Message: canShip is not defined
    at checked (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:263), <anonymous>:3:112)
    at init (static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:348)
    at static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:295
    at Object.ignore (static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:124)
    at static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:295
    at Object.arrayForEach (static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:12)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:294)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:283)
    at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:280)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:283)
```

This is the only code I could find that seemed to fit:

```
canShip: ko.pureComputed(function(){
                var canCreate = true;
                if(!CheckoutModel.createShipment()) {
                    canCreate = false;
                }
                var createShipButton = $('#can_ship');
                if(createShipButton.length > 0 && createShipButton.find('.ios-ui-select') != undefined){
                    var bootstrapSlide = createShipButton.find('.ios-ui-select');
                    if(canCreate == true){
                        bootstrapSlide.addClass('checked');
                    }else{
                        bootstrapSlide.removeClass('checked');
                    }
                }
                return canCreate;
            }),
```

Comment: You should ask the developer, we can't really give answers for 3rd party extensions here. But can you post a bit more of the 2nd code snippet?